# Reorder data frame values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a **`data frame`** (titled `EMG`), which has values (which, for example, go from a to u), which are organized like this:

```
a d g j m p s
b e h k n q t
c f i l o r u
```

Instead, I want it to be organized like this

```
a b c d e f g
h i j k l m n
o p q r s t u
```

I can't use transpose, because that would transpose the whole data frame. Is there any way to reorder the values horizontally instead of vertically?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all your columns are of the same `type`, then you can `unlist` the data frame, create a matrix that is filled by row (not the default by column) and then re-coerce to data.frame.

eg

```
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(EMG),nrow=3,byrow=TRUE))
##   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
## 1  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
## 2  h  i  j  k  l  m  n
## 3  o  p  q  r  s  t  u
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is `df`, try:

```
t(matrix(unlist(df), nrow=ncol(df)))
```